# how to wait for Modal response inside a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, asynchronous, modal-dialog

I have a loop that processing contacts.
Some contacts requires user modifications before continuing, so information is sent to a modal.
My problem is how to wait for the response without breaking the loop?

I have also tried to save the object that I was looping on and continue processing when I got response from the ui modal. it didn't work as well.

Here is some code:

```
/**
 * Processes contacts, either creating or updating them in Google Contacts.
 * Handles contacts that require user input separately.
 *
 * @param {Object} leads - The leads object containing contacts and labels.
 * @param {number} currentIndex - The index of the contact to start processing from.
 */
function processContacts(leads, currentIndex) {
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < leads.contacts.length; i++) {
    let contact = leads.contacts[i];
    if (contact.needsEdit) {
      Logger.log(`contact ${contact.Name} needs edit`);
      utils_saveContactInfoAsProperty(contact, i, leads);
      showEditNamesDialog(contact);
      break; // Exit the loop to wait for user input

      
    } else {
      Logger.log(`contact ${contact.Name} DOES NOT need edit`);
      //contacts_createOrUpdate(contact, leads.labels);
    }
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * Resumes the lead processing after receiving updated names from the HTML form.
 * It updates the contact information with the new names and then resumes the
 * processing of contacts from the current index.
 *
 * @param {string} firstName - The updated first name from the user.
 * @param {string} lastName - The updated last name from the user.
 */
function resumeLeadProcessing(firstName, lastName) {
  try {

    // Retrieve the stored contact information, its index in the leads array, and the leads object.
    var { contact, index, leads } = utils_retrieveContactInfoForProcessing();

    // Update the contact's name with the new values and mark it as not needing further editing.
    leads.contacts[index].firstName = firstName;
    leads.contacts[index].lastName = lastName;
    leads.contacts[index].Name = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    leads.contacts[index].needsEdit = false;

    // Continue processing the leads array starting from the current index.
    processContacts(leads, index);
  } catch (e) {
    // Log any errors encountered during the processing.
    Logger.log('Error in resumeLeadProcessing: ' + e.message);
  }
}
```

```
  <script>
        function saveName() {
            var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
                google.script.host.close();
                console.log('DONE!')
            }).resumeLeadProcessing(firstName, lastName);
        }
    </script>
```

it seems like they are running on different threads....

I tried many things...
the problem that I can't debug the server side code called from the client side...is there a way to have a breakpoint on apps script console that will be triggered by client side google.script.run?

I may using wrong data handling model...please advise

Comment: I'd process the ones I can, inform the ones I can't and delete the ones that don't answer.

Comment: `it didn't work as well.`. Please be more descriptive. What happens? What's supposed to happen? Show `utils_*` functions. Another idea is to send the index from server to client  and then back to server. I think Cooper's method is better though - instead of a modal, throw them all in a sidebar at the end of processing... this is also better from a end user perspective, rather than waiting for a modal to show up, they can batch input any modifications...